# Error: CakephpController could not be found

Tags: cakephp, controller

I installed CakePhp 3.1.6 on ubuntu. The below picture is the page that comes up:

[image: Error: CakephpController could not be found]

Do I have to create CakephpController?

I don't changed my cakephp codes, Could there be a problem with the settings?

Please help me.

Comment: Point your browser to `localhost`. That's the root of your app. You need to create controllers for your app to do something.

Comment: I 'm working with cakephp for the first time. Please  Help more. I tested, there is this problem with other cakephp project.

Comment: Please make sure you complete the [CakePHP 3 Tutorials](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html). It's the best way of learning.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, your app/server/virtual domain root should point to the webroot folder:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html

Alternativelly, you can start it from the console :
Bin/cake server